# Download from MEDIA_ROOT does not work

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I'm trying to make one `User` to upload a file (in some language) and another `User` to download it so they can translate it.

I've set media root adn media url:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

When someone uploads a file through `form`, the file appeares in `project/media/file`. But the problem is that if I try to click on the file or type an `url` `/project/media/file.extension` it raises

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/File_-_Psychos_lZB1D1N.mp3
Using the URLconf defined in SolutionsForLanguages_2.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/File_-_Psychos_lZB1D1N.mp3`

What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are on the development server? Add this to the `urls.py` config file to tell Django's development server to serve `static/` and `media/` files too.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```